# Language, sidebar.php wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I got a problem on this link:
[Videomarathon](http://truestories.dk/videomarathon/jury/)

On the right side, I'm showing recent posts,and have changed the text to "Se tidligere års jury"..
My problem is that the page doesn't show the danish letter "å"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the character isn't encoded correctly, so in your html, you should do something like this:

& aring;rs jury

remove the space between the & and the a.

I can see that you're also using cufon on the site, so you might need to re-download the font pack include (in the include the following glyphs section) any special danish characters as glyphs, or include a set of glyphs that contain the danish characters.

Comment: it doesn't work with the & aring;
removed the javascript that made the cufon. thanks.